# how to turn this piece of code into static polymophism?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to study static polymophism and I implemented the following code. Thanks to the comments from StackOverflow members, I came to understand that what I just wrote is not static polymophism, but actually template-based policy-pattern.

Can anyone give any insight about how to turn this piece of code into static polymophism?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Interface {
    T ex;
public:
    double getData() {
        return ex.getData(0);
    }
};

class Extractor1 {
public:
    double getData(const int a) {
        return 1;
    }
};

class Extractor2 {
public:
    double getData(const int a) {
        return 2;
    }
};


int main() {

    // here is the problem: the following 2 variables belong to different types. Therefore, I cannot create an array of pointers which point to the base class
    Interface<Extractor1> e1;
    Interface<Extractor2> e2;

    std::cout<<"FE1 "<< e1.getData() <<" FE2 "<< e2.getData()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Static polymorphism and static functions are pretty orthogonal. This is a regular template, nothing special. If you're looking for more, try policy-based design.

Comment: welcome to templates

Comment: Static polymorphism and static functions have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: _The next big confusing relationship after the one between Java and JavaScript_...

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this to achieve static polymorphism:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Interface {
public:
  double getData(int a) {
    return static_cast<T *>(this)->getData(a);
  }
};

class Extractor1 : public Interface<Extractor1> {
public:
  double getData(int a) {
    return 1;
  }
};

class Extractor2 : public Interface<Extractor2> {
public:
  double getData(int a) {
    return 2;
  }
};

int main() {
  Interface<Extractor1> e1;
  Interface<Extractor2> e2;

  std::cout << e1.getData(1) << " " << e2.getData(2) << std::endl;
}
```

The advantage of using static polymorphism is you avoid paying the runtime cost of a vtable lookup like you would when using virtual functions. The drawback though, as I see you are running into based on your 'array' comment, is that you cannot place these different Extractor classes into an array or any other container, because they are both inheriting different base types. The only way around this, aside from using something like a tuple or a container filled with boost::any types, is creating a common base class for your Extractor classes.